# Shortest and most efficient way to query ALL accessible fields of an object

Tags: apex, soql, security, field-level-security, spring-20

Now that `stripInaccessible()` and `WITH_SECURITY_ENFORCED` are GA I wonder what is the most readable and efficient way to do a

```
SELECT all_accessible_fields_for_user FROM AnyObject WHERE Id = ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best I came up with myself:

```
public SObject queryAllAccessible(Id recordId) {
    SObjectType type = recordId.getSObjectType();
    List<String> allFields = new List<String>(type.getDescribe().fields.getMap().keySet());

    String soql = String.format('SELECT {0} FROM {1} WHERE Id = :recordId', 
                                new List<String>{ String.join(allFields, ','), ''+type });

    return Security.stripInaccessible(AccessType.READABLE, Database.query(soql))
                    .getRecords()[0];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The main problem at hand is determining which fields to include in a query.

Since this is, by necessity, a runtime calculation, we'll still need to use dynamic soql (i.e. `Database.query(querystring)`)

The `WITH_SECURITY_ENFORCED` keyword for SOQL appears to throw an exception if an inaccessible field is requested. Exceptions as flow control are a *bad idea*, and it doesn't tell us *which* fields were the problem. Doesn't seem that this would be helpful for the problem at hand.

`Security.stripInaccessible()` does allow us to figure out which fields aren't accessible, and doesn't throw an exception, but it requires something (results of a query, maybe an in-memory instance would also work) to presumably iterate through and test the object/field access.

I think going through the field describe info is still probably going to be the winner in terms of efficiency and length.

Something like...

```java
List<String> accessibleFieldApiNames = new List<String>();
for(Schema.SObjectField field :Schema.SObjectType.Account.fields.getMap().values()){
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult dfr = field.getDescribe();
    if(dfr.isAccessible()){
        accessibleFieldApiNames.add(dfr.getName());
    }
}

String dynamicQuery = 'SELECT {0} FROM {1} LIMIT 100';

List<Account> accounts = Database.query(String.format(dynamicQuery, new List<String>{
    String.join(accessibleFieldApiNames, ', '),
    'Account'
}));
```

I think that's going to be hard to beat. Using `Security.stripInaccessible()` requires that you are querying all fields to begin with, so I don't see a way around using the `DescribeFieldResult` bit at the beginning.

Comment: I think you are mostly right. But you still at the end need to call stripInaccessible because your isAccessible check is not per record.

Comment: @RobertSösemann The record-level issue would be solved by using the `with sharing` modifier in the class this is used in, wouldn't it?